# Is there any tool to convert .DSK to mp3 file?

Tags: apple-ii, disk-image, audio

I was looking into the Apple II disk server (See below for background information) and curious if there is a tool that can actually convert `.DSK` image to `.MP3` file, as the underlying [c2t](https://github.com/datajerk/c2t) only supports [WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) and [AIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format) format.

Does anybody have some experience on such kind of tool?

---

**Background**

[C2T](https://github.com/datajerk/c2t) is a very interesting hack allowing to load disk images via the cassette port and write them onto Apple floppies (140k Disk II) without any previous OS support on the II side. Quite handy to bootstrap a naked hardware setup. Please see [this article](https://github.com/datajerk/c2t/blob/master/article/article.pdf) for more details about inenr workings and handling.

The '[Online Apple II Disk Server](http://asciiexpress.net/diskserver/)' is a connected project offering a simple web interface to offer download of many disk images as audio or in WAV/AIFF format. Never been so simple to bootstrap an Apple II find using modern toolsets.

Comment: Specifically liked the FAQ for c2t on the github site: "Yeah, but why?" -  "You clearly do not understand the awesomeness of the Apple II, move along." Apparently, the author has a sense of humour.

Comment: What's your goal? If you want the audio files to be smaller for long-term storage, the best compression tool is c2t itself (i.e. just keep the images in .DSK format and "decompress" to playable audio with c2t as needed).

Comment: Why can't you convert it to a WAV then convert the WAV to MP3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[c2t](https://github.com/datajerk/c2t) converts from 140K disk images to audio files, though only AIFF or WAV files. It might take some experimentation to get MP3 encoding settings that work using the Apple II's `LOAD` command, though. `c2t-96h` encodes the 9600 baud audio data at 48kHz, so `lame -V2` has a fair chance of working

c2t is used by the amazing [Apple II Disk Server](http://asciiexpress.net/diskserver/). It allows you to create Apple II disks on a II+ or IIe (but *not* a IIgs) by loading via the cassette port. It's basically magic.

Comment: The original [Apple Game Server](https://sourceforge.net/projects/a2gameserver/) (by Blurry) which inspired this was even more magical. It booted the game over a serial port, found the disk RWTS on the fly and and replaced it with a serial port RWTS. That means it could handle full disk games that accessed the disk later - but over the serial port. This online version is simpler and more practical if you want to create disks.

Comment: @NickWestgate - yes, serial booting is exceptionally clever, but the ability to create system disks with your phone and an audio cable is pretty unbelievable until you see it done.

Comment: Just to clarify: c2t is a little like an archiver? You load the audio file into an Apple II with a Disk II and it writes a new copy of the disk, which you can then use?

Comment: yes, that's exactly how c2t's disk image mode  works

Comment: @Tommy It's basically a self-extracting archive.

Comment: @scruss: Well, no more unbelievable than a Walkman and DOS on a tape. ; - ) (Kind of like ADTPro.) But yeah, a lot of technical work has gone into the tools to make it as fast as possible, and it's very cool to have the titles handy in your pocket or in the cloud.

Answer (score 5):

You may try to convert the offered WAV/AIFF files into an MP3 using some offline tool (preferred) like [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) or an online conversion site like [this one](https://online-audio-converter.com/) (no endorsement whatsoever).

It's a trial and error process, as conversion might change the resulting sound. This is especially true for conversion into [MP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3), as it's not only a [lossy format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) (*1), but the process may as well include [resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3). MP3's lossy compression is based on a [psycho-acoustic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoacoustics) model, which means it saves data by eliminating frequencies (or limits their amount) when assumed they are not noticed. Just, target of this 'sound' isn't a human ear, but a computer, dropping (or dimming) frequencies may render the whole transfer impossible.

FFMPEG does offer [much control](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), but can't eliminate the basic issue, so enjoy the parameter-fiddling  - or rather use a WAV/AIFF player instead. Most devices can handle them anyway.

---

*1 - WAV and AIFF are not, which as well may be the reason MP3 hasn't been offered in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there any tool to convert .DSK to mp3 file?

That's a straight **No, it can't be done that simple**.

`.DSK` files are disk images, containing (usually) several files (of various type), while cassette data are single files (usually BASIC, but may be as well data, just with complete different handling than on a disk).

So the only solution here may be using some emulator to load files you want to convert (given they can be loaded single at all) and then save them as cassette output to MP3 (or wave). Or 'play' it via a sound port, connected to the IIe. If either is supported by the emulator that is.

But unless they are very simple self contained programs they won't be any useful after loading via cassette port, as they may want to use DOS function to access data - and there is no DOS on a cassette only IIe.

---

Ofc, there may be more to this, as the question is missing any description of the whole setup - and more important **why** you want to go that way.

Comment: It would be an interesting hack tho.  Crack open the dsk and let the user pick a file, then read the file data and modulate appropriately to wave or MP3.  Lots of fun code there...

Comment: Maybe best not to answer if you don't know the target machine and its users …

Comment: @scruss Raffzahn is one of the most knowledgable members here on the Apple II; cf. https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:6659+[apple-ii]

Comment: You may have overlooked the "an MP3 for the [Apple II disk server](http://asciiexpress.net/diskserver/)" part, which takes care of the "conversion".

Comment: @scruss Wooha! Guess what, that exeptional nifty hack of [c2t and the 'Disk Server'](http://asciiexpress.net/diskserver/video.mp4) completely passed below my radar - so I answered that question at face value with the little knowledge I have about the II. Mine just works (mostly) flawless since ~40 years, using a SSC for downloads. I guess the question wants some clarification, so non initiate ones will as well get the idea.

Comment: @Tommy - that's as may be, but even the most knowledgeable should be aware of the possibility of a [black swan](https://australianmuseum.net.au/learn/animals/birds/black-swan/). Raffzahn seems to be quite happy to hear of c2t, too.

Comment: @scruss while even the most fierce critic should be able to take a step back and read the question as it was written. Mind you, 'Disk Server' isn't any specific term and it originally didn't have any pointers or otherwise specific information. So calm down. And yes, you're right, I'm quite happy to hear what Egan created.